# Oracle SQL: Joining another table with one missing tuple

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I have the following two tables, one stores order information, one stores key|value information.

There is no `CD = D` for key `COLOR_CD`. I would like to join both tables to get all orders irregardless of the key|value pair not found in the `MASS_DECODE` table.

Can i get some help please :D

ORDER_INFORMATION

```
ORDER_NUMBER    |COLOR_CD   |
----------------|-----------|
1               |A          |
2               |B          |
3               |C          |
4               |D          |
```

MASS_DECODE

```
KEY         |CD             |VALUE      |
------------|---------------|-----------|
COLOR_CD    |A              |Green      |
COLOR_CD    |B              |Blue       |
COLOR_CD    |C              |Red        |
SIZE_CD     |A              |Large      |
SIZE_CD     |B              |Medium     |
SIZE_CD     |C              |Small      |
```

SQL:

```
select order_number, cd, value
from order_information
left outer join mass_decode 
on (color_cd = cd)
and key = 'COLOR_CD';
```

Outcome:

```
ORDER_NUMBER    |CD         |VALUE      |
----------------|-----------|-----------|
1               |A          |Green      |
2               |B          |Blue       |
3               |C          |Red        |
```

Expected:

```
ORDER_NUMBER    |CD         |VALUE      |
----------------|-----------|-----------|
1               |A          |Green      |
2               |B          |Blue       |
3               |C          |Red        |
4               |D          |NULL       |
```

**EDIT**: I am sorry i have presented incorrect information for my tables. Since been corrected.

Comment: just a guess: try `where order_information.key = 'KEY_A';`

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/573cd/7

Comment: @beherenow thank you so much for the elaborated fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
  from order_information oi
   left join mass_decode md 
     on (
            oi.color_cd = md.cd 
        and oi.key = md.key
     )
where oi.key = 'KEY_A';
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/573cd/11)

upd:

According to your updates:

```
select *
  from order_information oi
   left join mass_decode md 
     on oi.color_cd = md.cd
where md.key = 'COLOR_CD' or md.key is null;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c8359/4)

Comment: i am sorry i have presented incorrect information for my question. The tables and SQL are as follows..

Answer (score 1):

Your column names are ambiguous. You have two columns named the same in two tables, so which column does the key in your where clause refer to? I think in later versions of Oracle, this will actually give you an error. Try this:

```
select oi.order_number, oi.color_cd, md.value
from order_infomation oi
left outer join mass_decode md
on (oi.color_cd = md.cd)
where oi.key = 'KEY_A';
```

Edit:

Based on your response to @billy, it sounds like that wasn't working for you. You could also try putting the key predicate into the join clause:

```
select oi.order_number, oi.color_cd, md.value
from order_infomation oi
left outer join mass_decode md
on (oi.color_cd = md.cd) and oi.key = 'KEY_A';
```

Comment: you need additional join predicate on `key` column - otherwise you'll get seven rows instead of four. check my fiddle in comments

Comment: @eaolson i am sorry i have presented incorrect information for my question. The tables and SQL are as follows..

Answer (score 0):

This should do :

```
SELECT 
    order_number, 
    color_cd AS cd, 
    (
        SELECT value FROM mass_decode m2 WHERE m2.key = o.key AND m2.cd = o.color_cd
    ) AS value
FROM order_information o
WHERE o.key =  'KEY_A'
```